# "Cucina" vs "fornello"

Tags: meaning, translation, cooking

I am looking for the Italian words for *burner* (small cylindric bored metal through which gas passes and fire is lighted in a gas stove) and *stove* (set of 4/6 burners and an oven below them, usually used in domestic kitchens to cook food).

I think that *cucina* means *stove* and *fornello/fuoco* means *burner*, but oddly https://www.wordreference.com/enit/stove also gives *fornelli* and *fuochi* as translation of *stove*. Is that right?

I tried to clear up the question by reading http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fornello/, but  then I got more confused when I found the following sentence.

> **fornèllo** s. m. [dim. di *forno*]. – 1. […] *f[ornello] a gas*, apparecchio metallico dove i combustibili gassosi bruciano, senza produzione di ceneri, allo sbocco di apposite tubazioni fornite di speciali dispositivi per regolare l’efflusso e quindi la fiamma; nei fornelli a combustibile liquido, come l’alcol, il petrolio e la benzina, l’alimentazione della fiamma avviene per capillarità attraverso materiali tessili (stoppino, calzetta), o, nei tipi più moderni, sotto forma di gas prodotto per il calore e la pressione da combustibile liquido. Per analogia, *f[ornello] elettrico,* nome dato ad apparecchi, adoperati per gli usi anzidetti, in cui il calore è prodotto dalla corrente elettrica, e in partic[olare] alla piastra metallica delle cucine elettriche.

If I understood this definition right, *fornello* may either mean *stove* or *burner*. Is that right?

For instance, are the following sentences correctly translated?

- *This stove has 4 burners and an oven.* (*Questa cucina ha quattro fornelli/fuochi e un forno.*)
- *The left upper burner of my stove is not working.* (*Il bruciatore/fornello/fuoco superiore sinistro della mia cucina non funziona.*)

Comment: The more general word could be "bruciatore". For example, a house heating system normally has one bruciatore. Fornello is something to heath something else, often food and, correctly, "cucina" in this context means a set of fornelli (each one is or has a bruciatore)

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Sei sicuro che _bruciatore_ si dica specificamente per i fornelli, oltre a essere un termine generico per qualunque dispositivo in cui una cosa brucia? (Non l'ho mai sentito in questo contesto, ma magari è un termine tecnico.)

Comment: @DaG hai ragione, non credo che si dica... volevo solo rimarcare la differenza con cucina e fornello.

Comment: @DaG: According to Wikipedia, it's ["fornello"](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fornello) and ["bruciatore"](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruciatore), but I really thought that "i fornelli della cucina" were what Wikipedia call "bruciatori", so I'm also getting confused.

Comment: @DaG:  Questo [video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HDYOE0k3b8c) è chiamato "Come pulire i bruciatori dei fornelli", invece il titolo di questo articolo è "Come pulire i fornelli o fuochi in alluminio (facile e economico)".

Comment: @Charo: È possibile che “bruciatore” sia il termine più tecnico usato da chi lavora nel settore, ma nell'uso comune non credo proprio che molti dicano: “Ho messo la pentola con l'acqua sul bruciatore”.

Comment: @DaG: E invece si dice "fornello", ma "fornello" può anche essere l'intera cucina, vero?

Comment: @Charo Io non userei mai "fornello" per l'intera cucina.. solo per la parte dove si trova fisicamente la fiamma.

Comment: @Charo: In effetti ci sono varie sovrapposizioni: la cucina è tutto l'ambiente ma anche l'impianto con i fuochi/fornelli e il forno. Un fornello è solo uno dei fuochi, tendenzialmente, ma ci sono espressioni come “stare ai fornelli” per dire più in generale “cucinare”. “Fuoco” ha ovviamente varie sfumature di significato. Quindi, OP, i tuoi dubbi sono pienamente comprensibili.

Comment: @DenisNardin: E, allora, la definizione di "fornello" di Wikipedia non sarebbe corretta?

Comment: @Charo: La definizione della Wikipedia ha numerosi problemi; dire che un fornello è un piccolo forno è quanto meno riduttivo (un forno è per definizione chiuso), e la definizione di "forno" a cui rimanda è pure peggio.

Comment: @DaG: Allora, nel linguaggio comune,  [questo](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Cucina_Museo_scienza_e_tecnologia_Milano.jpg) sarebbe una "cucina a gas" e [questo](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/11/Cooking_with_gas.jpg) sarebbe un "fornello a gas", vero? D'altronde, questo era quello che pensavo io fino a quando ho letto questi articoli di Wikipedia, che mi hanno causato una grande confusione.

Comment: @apaderno Why have you rejected my edit? Why have you edited a direct quote?

Comment: @paderno also changed "for instance" to "for example" in my question. I have no idea why, given they are synonyms in English.

Answer (score 1):

> Italian words for "burner" (small cylindric bored metal through which gas passes and fire is lighted in a gas stove) and "stove" (set of 4/6 burners and an oven below them ...

In this context, use "cucina" for the appliance used to cook/heat food; it has one or more "fornello/i", or "fuoco/fuochi". More technically, a single "fornello" has a "bruciatore" (burner) which burns the gas, and something to hold a pot above the flame. A normal user could complain saying "the upper right burner doesn't work" ("il fornello/fuoco in alto a destra non funziona"); the technician would probably clean or substitute the burner ("bruciatore", only the part which produces the flame). Note also that a "fornello" can be electrical: in that case it has no burner.

You can also cook using a "stufa" (stove). The "stufa" burns mostly wood. From "stufa" derives the term "stufato" (cooked on a "stufa"); but "stufa" is also a burner used to heat a room, not especially designed to cook, where you can anyway put a pot on it to heat water or other meals.

> 1) I think that cucina = stove and fornello/fuoco = burner

Yes, this is quite right.

> 2) reading http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fornello/ ... 
>   If I understood this definition right, "fornello" may mean both "stove" and "burner". Is that right?

Not quite in this context. A "fornello" is what you use to heat a pot; a "cucina" typically has more than one "fornello" (otherwise it would be called simply "fornello"). A stove may also be used for that, especially if it is one designed not only to heat a room, but also to cook; in that case, the stove ("stufa") has an upper plate where you lay the pots, and an oven beside the burner.

> This stove has 4 burners and an oven. (= Questa cucina a quattro fornelli/fuochi e un forno)

Yes, this is almost completely correct: "Questa cucina **ha** quattro ...".

> The left upper burner of my stove is not working. (= Il bruciatore/fornello/fuoco superiore sinistro della mia cucina non funziona)

Yes again: perfectly translated. Congratulations.

--- EDIT after many comments ---

Actually not all the sources agree on "stufato", but I've found these:
https://educalingo.com/it/dic-it/stufato
  "In the dictionary, the first definition of stufato is *heated into a stove*"

https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/S/stufato.html
  "Heated in the stove"

https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/S/stufare.html
  "To heat inside a stove"

http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stufare/
  "To treat a product with heat in stoves or special containers"

My Zingarelli on paper from 2001 cites, as first meaning of "stufare", marked as rare or dismissed, "to heat inside a  stove".

Now, maybe "stufato" derive from "stufare" - not "stufa", but this is, I think, not very important for who asked the question. Instead, perhaps the whole sentence about the "stufato" could have been omitted; I wrote that to mark the meaning of something that was used to cook, but no more nowadays.

Comment: Yes, it is very uncommon that a participle develops into a noun.

Comment: Sorry, @Nico, I'm not sure whether «Yes, it is very uncommon that a participle develops into a noun» is a joke or a mistype or something, but: abitato, acciottolato, accusato, acetato, affamato, agglomerato, alleato, ammalato, armato, attentato, ...

Comment: Non ci siamo capiti. Quelli che tu citi sono conversioni e non derivazioni morfologiche come quelle di cui si parlava sopra.

Comment: _Stufato_ was originally the past participle of _stufare_, which in turn, comes from «lat. parl. _*extufāre_ ‘riscaldare’, comp. di _ĕx-_ (s-) e di un denominale del gr. _tŷphos_ ‘vapore, febbre’. V. _tifo_ ☼ 1287» (Zingarelli). _Stufa_ also derive from _stufare_.

Comment: Le versioni, come vedi dal link, variano: https://www.etimo.it/?term=stufa&find=Cerca  Inoltre mi augurerei che non fossi sempre sul piede di guerra ("joke" etc.). Argomentare in modo obiettivo non guasta specie fra adulti.

Comment: Non sono sul piede di nessuna guerra, @Nico, e scusami se sembrava. Temevo sinceramente di aver frainteso il tuo commento, e così è, a quel che dici. Poteva essere che mancasse un “not”, o qualcosa del genere. Visto che così non è, puoi spiegare meglio la differenza fra i due meccanismi con cui si passa da participi a nomi?

Comment: @Nico: Quanto a etimo.it, attenzione che va preso con un grosso granello di sale: è la scansione di un'opera datata e redatta da un dilettante. Se n'era già parlato e [qui](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1202/37) argomento meglio.

Comment: Nessun problema. Un altro link in cui si sostiene che "stufa" sia derivato dall'infinito eliminando il suffisso http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stufa  Intendi la differenza fra derivazione e conversione o il meccanismo ipotizzabile per la conversione dei participi in nomi?

Comment: @Nico: Siamo d'accordo che “stufa” derivi da “stufare”: l'ho scritto anch'io. :) Intendevo che intuisco il senso, ma non mi è del tutto chiaro, di «Quelli che tu citi sono conversioni e non derivazioni morfologiche». Aspetta, la pongo proprio come domanda.

Comment: Appunto, ma mi sembra implausibile che si sia passati da "stufare" al participio per poi "riderivare" da questo il sostantivo.

Comment: Scusa, @Nico, non mi è chiaro quest'ultimo commento. Una volta che esiste il verbo “stufare”, usare il suo participio come sostantivo non è una semplice conversione come, già solo in ambito culinario, “bollito”, “fritto” e molti altri?

Comment: In teoria sì, ma, a mio avviso, in questo caso no per un semplice motivo concettuale. Il "bollito" etc indicano prodotti ottenuti in seguito a un'attività compiuta e denotata dal participio. Il participio usato come sostantivo in questo caso è attribuibile all'omissione del sostantivo ("cibo bollito" et similia). Ora, non è che il participio "stufato" possa produrre uno strumento come la stufa...

Comment: Ah, ecco, avevo frainteso di nuovo. Parlavo del passaggio da “stufare” a “stufato”, non a “stufa”: per quest'ultimo il Treccani se la cava con la derivazione da “stufare” (come Zingarelli e altri) “a suffisso zero”.

Comment: Forse l'equivoco deriva dalla tua citazione iniziale di "stufato".

Comment: @Charo È possibile eliminare la frase di stufato. Dai anche un'occhiata a https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/it-wont-work-it-doesnt-work.2689615/

Comment: @Nico non so se ho capito la diatriba, ma vorrei solo aggiungere che nella mia regione "il bollito" è un piatto ben preciso, mentre "il fritto" non indica niente di preciso (esiste però "il fritto misto alla piemontese").

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica In realtà non era una diatriba, ma una discussione leggermente OT vista a posteriori. Il discorso è che comunque sia "fritto" sia "bollito" sono in origine participi e non sostantivi. Purtroppo non siamo in un posto per disquisire di cucina, ma a me piacciono comunque molto sia il bollito sia il frittomisto ;-)

Comment: @Nico ho scritto diatriba senza intenderlo veramente, diciamo discussione costruttiva. E sì, fritto e bollito sono in origine participi, ma a volte diventano sostantivi con un significato molto preciso.

Comment: D'accordissimo ;-)

Comment: What's the problem with this answer now? (I ask this because of the downvote). I would like to know it because, as I have said in a previous comment, after reading Wikipedia articles, I felt somewhat  confused about the use of this vocabulary.

Comment: Where is the downvote? I can't see any...

Comment: @nico go to the (mine) user profile, select activity, then reputation, and you will see the history.

Comment: Davvero un peccato. Dei siti che frequento qui mi era parso uno dei più "civili". Non te la prendere. Ti ho dato un like perché il contributo era davvero valido!

Comment: Grazie per la risposta! Tutta la discussione su "stufato" sembra irrilevante per la domanda posta e potrebbe essere cancellata, ma ho comunque dato un voto positivo perché il resto della risposta è molto chiara.