# Participles into nouns

Tags: etymology

In the context of [this answer](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/11488/37), while discussing the etymology of *stufato*, it was said that “it is very uncommon that a participle develops into a noun”, mentioning that it is necessary to distinguish between “conversions” and “morphological derivations” (if I'm getting it right), with the latter quite more frequent: *abitato*, *acciottolato*, *accusato*, *acetato*, *affamato*, *agglomerato*, *alleato*, ...

Can someone clarify better the situation?

Answer (score 2):

Conversions are a subtype of what is canonically labelled "derivation".
Conversions imply the categorical change of a word without additional morphology. Examples: verbs into nouns ("il dovere/potere/volere" in Italian or "the might" in English) including verbal participles such as the ones listed in the answer linked above ("abitato" etc). 
In contrast, derivational morphology is the mechanism by which categorical change takes place via affixes ("confess" leads to "confessION").

Answer (score 1):

Il libro [*Competenze linguistiche per l’accesso all’università*](https://www.academia.edu/17918108/Competenze_linguistiche_per_l_accesso_all_universit%C3%A0?auto=download) di Grazia Basile, Anna Rosa Guerriero e Sergio Lubello (Università di Salerno) ha una sezione intitolata "La formazione delle parole" in cui, tra altri meccanismi, menziona i seguenti:

> **La derivazione**     Abbiamo visto che uno dei serbatoi dell’italiano è rappresentato dalle neoformazioni (cfr. PAR. 3.1.2). In gran parte si tratta di formazioni endogene, cioè di parole che si formano 
>   a partire da altre già esistenti nell’italiano (*basi*) attraverso elementi, 
>   gli *affissi*, che si aggiungono all’inizio della base (*prefissi*; ad es. ***s***cambiare, ***in***utile, ***dis***illuso) o alla fine della base (*suffissi*; ad es. *parol**aio***, 
>   *mur**etto***, *giornal**ista***): i due processi sono chiamati rispettivamente *prefissazione* e *suffissazione*. Le basi italiane sono in genere nomi, 
>   verbi e aggettivi, più raramente avverbi (*indietro* > *indietreggiare*) e 
>   locuzioni (*me ne frego* > *menefreghismo*). 
>   [...]
>
> **Processi di conversione e riduzione**     Un’altra possibilità di 
>   formare nuove parole è la derivazione da altre preesistenti cambiando 
>   semplicemente la categoria grammaticale, senza bisogno di suffisso o 
>   prefisso: il processo si chiama *conversione*; l’aggettivo *bianco* diventa 
>   sostantivato *i bianchi*, così la *finanziaria*, la *metropolitana*. Casi frequenti sono quelli dell’infinito sostantivato (*il bere*, *il dovere*, *gli averi*), 
>   del participio presente che diventa sostantivo (*il cantante*, *la badante*, 
>   *gli abbaglianti*), della formazione di sostantivi dal participio passato 
>   (*l’udito*), dal gerundio (*crescendo*), da locuzioni (*viavai*, *nullaosta*). 
>   Sono considerati processi di conversione anche quelli che producono 
>   formazioni senza un vero e proprio suffisso ma con l’aggiunta di desinenze/morfemi verbali (tali formazioni sono anche dette a suffisso zero): *capitano* > *capitanare*, *soppalco* > *soppalcare*, *martello* > *martellare*, *cestino* > *cestinare* (Grossmann, Rainer, 2004, pp. 534-6). 
>   [...]

Quindi, è frequente la formazione di sostantivi da participi passati tramite questo processo di conversione come, per esempio, quelli citati nella domanda.